# ERROR running auth:sfdxurl:store: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')

Tags: salesforcedx, sfdx-plugin, sfdx-error, vscode-dx

**How to Replicate:**

Running this command `sfdx auth:sfdxurl:store -f ./SFDX_TMP_URL.txt -s -a integration` to authenticate via sfdxAuthUrl.

`SFDX_TMP_URL.txt` contains the sfdxAuthUrl value.

**Error:**

After running the command it returns `ERROR running auth:sfdxurl:store:  Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')`
[image]

**SFDX Info**

```
$ sfdx --version
sfdx-cli/7.159.0 darwin-x64 node-v16.15.1

$ sfdx plugins --core
@oclif/plugin-autocomplete 0.3.0 (core)
@oclif/plugin-commands 1.3.0 (core)
@oclif/plugin-help 3.3.1 (core)
@oclif/plugin-not-found 1.2.6 (core)
@oclif/plugin-plugins 1.10.11 (core)
@oclif/plugin-update 1.5.0 (core)
@oclif/plugin-warn-if-update-available 1.7.3 (core)
@oclif/plugin-which 1.0.4 (core)
@salesforce/sfdx-plugin-lwc-test 1.0.0 (core)
alias 2.1.0 (core)
apex 1.1.0 (core)
auth 2.2.2 (core)
community 2.0.0 (core)
config 1.4.14 (core)
custom-metadata 2.0.0 (core)
data 2.0.4 (core)
generator 2.0.2 (core)
info 2.0.1 (core)
limits 2.0.1 (core)
org 2.0.2 (core)
salesforce-alm 54.6.2 (core)
schema 2.1.1 (core)
sfdx-cli 7.159.0 (core)
sfdx-git-delta 5.3.0
signups 1.2.0 (core)
source 2.0.7 (core)
telemetry 2.0.0 (core)
templates 55.0.0 (core)
trust 2.0.1 (core)
user 2.1.0 (core)
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour).  Including a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful. An example of a question with minimal repro details along the lines of yours is https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/1298

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have faced the same issue when our sandboxes migrated to the next release and Enhanced Domain feature was enabled.

I have opened SF Support case to find an answer to this.

The issue should affect only sandboxes since their domains were migrated and changed.

To fix the problem, you need to update your Auth URL to contain the new domain, that is, replace content of file `./SFDX_TMP_URL.txt`

```
force://PlatformCLI::AUTH_URL_TOKEN@production--full.my.salesforce.com
```

with

```
force://PlatformCLI::AUTH_URL_TOKEN@production--full.sandbox.my.salesforce.com
```

Answer (score 0):

It might help you. I received the same issue, and I added '.' at the end of auth URL in the file:

1. Old one force://PlatformCLI::xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.my.salesforce.com
2. New one force://PlatformCLI::xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.my.salesforce.com.

and it works

Comment: well, this didn't work to me, when I tried to add a dot, it fails with another error ERROR running auth:sfdxurl:store:  Could not retrieve the username after successful auth code exchange.

Due to: request to /services/oauth2/userinfo failed, reason: read ECONNRESET